# get a list of values to represent x,y on Cartesian

Tags: java, arrays, random

For my homework I am making a predator/prey on a grid like Conway's Game of Life. It is looking good but at one point is crude.

Many times from a current cell I need to pick an adjacent cell at random and perform some action, then cycle through the other three cells (I'm only using side cells, not diagonals. The current cell on the grid we can call position x=0 and y=0).

Doing the cycle is no problem if I always start at one place like (-1,0) then walk through (0,1)(+1,0)(0,-1). But that is not a random start point.

I can get a random start cell with math.random() for x and y.

What vexes me is a *smart* way to define x,y of next cell in cycle when I don't know ahead the cell that will be the random start. I can do by brute force by having an if(x==1 && y==0) then three lines doing tasks in the other three cells. Then if(x==0 && y=1) and another three lines. But that is three lines for each of four possible starts. Seems crude.

I thought maybe I could describe the x,y of all four cells in an array of 8 members: x top, y top, x right, y right...). Then gen a random number to select a "start point" and walk through. At last member loop back to beginning of array until have read out the four pairs of x,y.

Before writing and troubleshooting that, is there a smarter way? If there are a couple ideas I'd try to code up each for the practice.

I could also use some guidance on how I could have phrased this problem for a search.

Much thanks.

Comment: When you say "cycle through the other three cells", do you mean clockwise/counterclockwise rotation? Or do you just mean that you need to perform some operation on the other three cells, with order not being important? Because in the latter case, you can just cycle over all *four* adjacent cells, but skipping the "start cell".

Comment: Once the start cell is randomly selected, the actions on the others can proceed clockwise from the start cell.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to process a random cyclic permutation of the adjacent cells. You can do this with one level of indexing indirection. For instance, you can define the indexes of the adjacent cells by the array

```
int[] adjacent = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

Then you want to start at a random place in `adjacent` and process the four elements in order, wrapping around to the start if you run off the end. You can handle this by either using the modulus operator (`%`) or by doubling the array:

```
int[] adjacent = {0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3};
int randomStart = rand.nextInt(4); // rand is an instance of Random
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    processNeighbor(adjacent[randomStart + i]);
}
```

This will process the neighbors in one of the following possibilities, chosen at random:

- 0, 1, 2, 3
- 1, 2, 3, 0
- 2, 3, 0, 1
- 3, 0, 1, 2

Answer (score 0):

you could take a circular linked list approach

each node has a reference to the next node with the last nodes reference to the 
first node(hence circular;

then you could do

```
Node startNode = randomStartNode(list);
Node nextNode = startNode;
do{

    // do something;

    nextNode = nextNode.next();   
}while (startNode != nextNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way to iterate through neighbours is to store the offset for each direction:

```
int[] dx = { 1, 0, -1, 0 }; // change in x for each direction
int[] dy = { 0, 1, 0, -1 }; // change in y for each direction
```

A simple iteration would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < dx.length; i++)
    process(x + dx[i], y + dy[i]);
```

In your case, you can choose a random direction and loop through the rest:

```
int special = rand.nextInt(dx.length);
processSpecial(x + dx[special], y + dy[special]);

for (int i = 0; i < dx.length; i++)
    if (i != special)
        process(x + dx[i], y + dy[i]);
```

Or you can loop through in a cycle, starting at one past the random direction:

```
int special = rand.nextInt(dx.length);
processSpecial(x + dx[special], y + dy[special]);

for (int i = (special + 1) % dx.length; i != special; i = (i + 1) % dx.length)
    process(x + dx[i], y + dy[i]);
```

In the last two snippets, `rand` is an instance of [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). A single instance should be created and shared throughout the program.